# Hosting RTD documentation in a subfolder of existing domain

Tags: read-the-docs

I currently have documentation built by readthedocs.org on docs.mycompany.com and my regular company website on mycompany.com. For SEO purposes I would prefer to have the documentation on mycompany.com/docs, so my documentation content contributes to the company website ranking.

From the [documentation on custom domains](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_domains.html) I can only find subdomain examples. Am I correct in thinking the above is not possible with readthedocs.org and would require me to start self-hosting the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Docs cannot control your root domain (`mycompany.com`) if you have something else hosted there. You could put a reverse proxy listening at `/docs` on your `mycompany.com` domain pointing to your `<project-slug>.readthedocs.io` URL.